# terraform plan output redirection to file does not capture error messages

Tags: unix, terraform

I had previously successfully captured `terraform plan` outputs to a file by using the unix output redirections like this:

```sh
tf plan -no-color > plan.txt
```

When my `plan` (or `apply`) has errors, the output text file is empty although I see the error messages in the terminal output.

How can I capture output even in the cases there are errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that it is because of stderr (standard error) and stdout (standard output) outputs in unix, when referring to the information [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-redirect-standard-error-in-bash/).

`2>` can be used to redirect stderr.
`&>` can be used to redirect both stdout and std err.
`1>` or `>` can be used to redirect stdout.

Eventually I used this command to redirect to 2 files (as I preferred):

```sh
tf plan -no-color 2> err.txt 1> out.txt
```

**More info**

My initial command,

```sh
tf plan -no-color > plan.txt
```

will only redirect stdout to the file.

Hence when the plan had errors, there was no stdout, the empty output overwrote and emptied my `plan.txt` file, and the errors went to stderr.

Comment: Thanks, for me, some of the output from stderr was not included when I used TF_LOG_PATH. This helped me capture everything.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to redirect everything you can do the following:

```
tf plan -no-color > plan.txt 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1):

Terraform has a built in variable `TF_LOG_PATH` to redirect all output including errors to a specific file. You don't need to redirect the output.

example:

```
export TF_LOG_PATH=/mydirectory/mylogfile.log
terraform plan
```

Source: https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/debugging.html